# How to put animated collapse close in my menu, when click outside the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My navbar is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4Ts/3/

my html code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function CloseNav() {
        $(".navbar-collapse").stop().css({ 'height': '1px' }).removeClass('in').addClass("collapse");
        $(".navbar-toggle").stop().removeClass('collapsed');
    }

    $('html').click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse in");
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
            CloseNav();
        }

    });
});
```

How to put animated collapse closing in my menu, when click outside the button. It´s close when click outside the button but without animation effetc. How to menu button change color only when the collapse is open?

Comment: For the animation you can use http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: My javascript knowledge is very pover. I need jQuery function. Thanks

Comment: Nobody is going to write code for you. You have to learn it by the resources given.

Comment: @user3216077 `animate()` *is* a jQuery function

Comment: flec - I know it, but if I would have time for learn it, and wouldn´t have try,  I didn't ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution may work for you. Switch your CloseNav() function to below:

```
    function CloseNav() {
        $(".navbar-collapse").stop().animate({'height': 0},300, function () {
            $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in').addClass("collapse");
        });
        $(".navbar-toggle").stop().removeClass('collapsed');
    };
```

It looks like just adding the `.collapse` class to the nav bar will just switch the height immediately. If you make an animation and then add the class it creates the slide up effect you wanted.

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/Hg4Ts/4/)**

Comment: Thank you. Do you saw my second question: How to menu button change color only when the collapse is open, and with click for close collpase in it, come back to start color, and not focused?

Comment: I don't see any CSS in your post, but that would be where I would start. Try looking at `:hover` functionality or add some styles to one of the classes already being applied via the JS when it's open.

Comment: I try this and :focus, :active, and didn´t result. I think that only javascript make it. Thank you one more time.